# How do I fix the shopping cart number when no users are logged in?

Tags: php, mysql

I started a course on Udemy: PHP for beginners 2023, Build a complete ECommerce store. I've managed to follow everything without any issues, but I have a problem with showing the number of products in cart.

The issue only happens when there are no users logged in. I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing wrong and the course lecturer isn't responding to questions.

I receive the following errors

> Notice: Undefined variable: getNumber in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\bookstore\includes\header.php on line 63
>
> Notice: Trying to get property 'num_products' of non-object in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\bookstore\includes\header.php on line 63

I'm using XAMPP and MySQL. Code is written on Visual Studio. I added the code below.

Header - Line 63:

```
<a class="nav-link active  text-white" aria-current="page" href="<?php echo APPURL;?>/shopping/cart.php"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>(<?php echo $getNumber->num_products; ?>)</a>
```

Header - lines 9-13 (this is where I think the error actually is)

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    $number = $conn->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as num_products FROM cart WHERE user_id='$_SESSION[user_id]'");
    $number->execute();

    $getNumber = $number->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

}
```

I was previously directed to the Stack Overflow question below, but I didn't find it helpful.
[how do i fix the shopping cart number when no users are logged in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75585137/how-do-i-fix-the-shopping-cart-number-when-no-users-are-logged-in?noredirect=1#comment133354632_75585137)

Bear in mind, I am following the course as accurately as possible, so things like `query()` using `execute()` is how it is being passed on in the course. `$_SESSION['user_id']` is also set. The issue isn't with users logged in, but when nobody is logged in.

I realised I should also point out that the original error was

> Notice: Undefined index: user_id in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\bookstore\includes\header.php on line 11

where line 11

```
$number = $conn->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_products FROM cart WHERE user_id='$_SESSION[user_id]'");
```

So, maybe my attempted solution is incorrect?

Comment: `query()` doesn't use `execute()`. Is `$_SESSION['user_id']` set? You should not have values in SQL. Use prepared statements and bind values in via parameterized queries.

Comment: none of my query() commands work without executing. the $_SESSION['user_id'] is set for when a user is logged in, so i have all the data being collected etc. the issue is when there is no user logged in.